# Python use array axis to select slice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a function that accepts an multi-dimensional array, an axis number and the index I would like to get:

```
def get_slice(my_array, dimension, index):
    if dimension == 0:
        slice = my_array[index, :, :]
    elif dimension == 1:
        slice = my_array[:, index, :]
    else:
        slice = my_array[:, :, index]
    return np.squeeze(slice)
```

But, I now have to change the code to accept 4 dimensions and I was wondering if there is a more general way to do this in python?

So, I am looking for a function that accepts an general n-dimension array, a dimension (axis) and an index to select on that dimension/axis and returns me the entire slice of that index on that dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it's not too difficult actually:

```
def get_slice(my_array, dimension, index):
    items = [slice(None, None, None)] * my_array.ndim
    items[dimension] = index
    array_slice = my_array[tuple(items)]
    return np.squeeze(array_slice)
```

---

Although I don't think it helps you here, if you ever have a function and you want to slice along the first dimension or the last dimension, you can use `Ellipsis`:

```
def get_slice_along_first_dim(array_with_arbitrary_dimensions, idx):
    return array_with_arbitrary_dimensions[idx, ...]

def get_slice_along_last_dim(array_with_arbitrary_dimensions, idx):
    return array_with_arbitrary_dimensions[..., idx]
```

You can even do stuff like:

```
arr[..., 3, :, 8]
arr[1, ..., 6]
```

if I recall correctly.  the `Ellipsis` object just fills in as many empty slices as it needs to in order to fill out the dimensionality.

What you can't do is have more than 1 ellipsis object passed to `__getitem__`:

```
arr[..., 1, ...]  # Fail.
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you for sharing. I use both your answer on top aswell as the function get_slice_along_last_dim() which I also needed.